# Convert varchar datetime without dashes and colon to varchar datetime with dashes and colon

Tags: sql-server

I want to convert this `20201001163318` `varchar` date & time to something like this `2020-10-01 16:33:18`.

I tried this

```
select convert(varchar, getdate(), 25)
```

but it does not work

Comment: `convert(varchar, getdate(), 25) ` would convert the value returned from `GETDATE()` (which is a `datetime`, not a `varchar`) *into* a `varchar` in the format of style code 25,which is `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss.mmm`.

Comment: *Hopefully* this isn't a column in your database; if it is I strongly recommend fixing your design and not storing dates in a `varchar`. If the value if coming from an application, I do recommend re-evaluating the code, and ensuring you pass a date and time data type, not a `varchar`.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps `stuff()` in concert with a `try_convert()`

**Example**

```
declare @S varchar(50) = '20201001163318'

Select try_convert(varchar(19),try_convert(datetime,stuff(stuff(stuff(@S,13,0,':'),11,0,':'),9,0,' ')),120)
```

**Returns**

```
(No column name)
2020-10-01 16:33:18
```

Also if you wanted to convert getdate() to a string, you could try:

```
Select convert(varchar(19),getdate(),120)
```